# How can I determine the User-Agent for an iOS application's HTTP request?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, http

I have an iOS application that downloads an xml file using:

```
NSURL *queryURL = [NSURL URLWithString:query];
NSData *xmlData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:queryURL];
```

The call is made to a third-party, so I'm not in control of the servers.  The third party needs to know what that user-agent is (they are optimizing the feed based on the user-agent)

My question is how can I determine what my user-agent is?  I don't specifically set that anywhere and didn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the name of your app (bundle identifier).  In the end I just wrote a quick method to call a web server I do have control of, launched the app, and then read the logs from that web server and I could see the exact user-agent information.

Answer (score 0):

The user-agent is undocumented and subject to change. If you want to control the user-agent header, you will need to use `NSURLConnection` with an `NSMutableRequest`. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-170129) has an example of how to use `NSURLConnection`.