# What HTTP User-Agent does my iOS program advertise itself as?

Tags: ios, user-agent

I've written an app for my podcast, [Otaku no Podcast](http://otakunopodcast.com/).  In various parts of the app, I use `NSURLConnection` (fetch RSS feeds), `UIWebView` (display website content), `AVPlayer` (play MP3 audio files off our CDN), and `MPMoviePlayerViewController` (play video files off our CDN).  Now, since all of these make HTTP requests of some sort, I'm assuming that they will advertise themselves with the standard iPhone User-agent string.  (if my assumption is incorrect please let me know)  This means that, based on reading my log files, I have no way of telling which of my visitors is coming in via plain old mobile Safari, vs. using my app.

Is there a way of changing the User-Agent to one of my own?  I found [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361028/how-can-i-determine-the-user-agent-for-an-ios-applications-http-request) that describes how to do this with `NSURL` but I can't find any information about any of the above classes that I am using.

Answer (score 10):

Your original assumption is partly incorrect- A custom User-agent string is used for NSURLRequests from your app. In my testing, the string is

```
<product-name>/<build-number> CFNetwork/548.0.3 Darwin/11.2.0
```

However, some requests from UIWebView use this user-agent string

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone Simulator; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/9A334
```

presumably so that websites can optimise their HTML for the device even if it's not MobileSafari.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://www.mphweb.com/en/blog/easily-set-user-agent-uiwebview) blog post, you may be able to set a pseudo-global User-Agent string (pseudo in that I'm not sure which other classes outside of `UIWebView` use it).

> Here is the class method to add to your main controller (or app delegate) :

```
+ (void)initialize {
    // Set user agent (the only problem is we can't modify it later)
    NSDictionary *dictionary =
    [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
     @"Your desired user agent", @"UserAgent", nil];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
    [dictionary release];
}
```

According to the comments on that post, "we can't modify it later" is a bit of an overstatement: you can modify the `UserAgent` value later, but you have to `release` and re-`alloc` any `UIWebView`s (and I presume `NSURLConnection`s if they use it too) for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this related question ( [Changing the userAgent of NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532206/changing-the-useragent-of-nsurlconnection) ), it looks like it is pretty easy to make a user-agent change for NSURLConnection.

As for the other classes (UIWebView, AVPlayer, MPMoviePlayerViewController), there's no easy way to mess with the underlying NSURLConnections.

If you really want to change the user-agent for all HTTP requests, I'd suggest looking into [Objective-C Class Posing](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ClassPosing) to replace NSURLConnection (which hopefully wouldn't require completely reimplementing it).